# Test the pointers using relational operator in for loop

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose I have the for loop which store zeros in an array using pointers like this:

```
int *vp, values[5];

for(vp = &values[5-1]; vp >= &values[0]; vp--)
   *vp = 0;
```

The book-*Pointers on C* said that there is a problem with this loop, because the comparison `vp >= &values[0]` is undefined as it moved outside of the bounds of the array. But How?

Comment: It's 'undefined', but on 95% of systems it will be fine. The *only* scenario where the comparison will fail will be if `&values[0]` == 0x0.

Comment: Probably more than 95%. =)

Comment: I'll bet it wouldn't work on the C implementation on Symbolics Lisp Machines. I have no idea whether there are still any in use, though; the company went out of business almost 20 years ago.

Comment: I take it back, it might have worked. Symbolics C performed bounds checking, but I think only when dereferencing pointers. Since this doesn't dereference, it probably worked because `vp` starts out pointing to the same array object. Its pointers were implemented as a pair of `array, index`, and I don't think there was any problem with `index` decrementing below 0.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't use direct-inequality with a post-decrement. Something like `for (vp=values+N; vp-- != values;)` where `N` is the magnitude of your array?

Comment: @WhozCraig that's a matter of style

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I was specifically asking in addressing the OP's observation from the mentioned text about evaluating an array-based pointer before the first element, which is in-fact undefined, rather than one-past the last element, which *is* defined by the standard. I didn't intend it to be a "this is another way" comment, and apologize if it was taken as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a pointer is equivalent to an unsigned integer, we can see that the problem would only exist if `values` started at address 0, in which case the pointer would wrap around after being decremented and become `UINT_MAX`.

To visualize the problem, let's step through what happens, assuming `values` starts at address 0x0:

```
iteration 1: 
vp = 0x4, *vp = 0;

iteration 2:
vp = 0x3, *vp = 0;

iteration 3: 
vp = 0x2, *vp = 0;

iteration 4:
vp = 0x1, *vp = 0;

iteration 5:
vp = 0x0, *vp = 0;

iteration 6:
vp = 0xFFFFFFFF; *vp = ?? // uh oh!
```

Thus, `vp` would never be less than the minimum value for a pointer (which is 0), and it would result in an infinite loop (assuming all memory is writable), or a segmentation fault.

It is also undefined behavior according to the standard (as you can address one element after an array, but not before it), but in actuality, this should never fail on any realistic system.

Comment: So, it's safe to use this or I can check for greater than only.

Comment: @ashish2expert Yes, it's my assessment that it is safe, unless you're dealing with a very strange system (which you probably aren't here).

Comment: This code can fail on implementations with segment-and-offset pointers, but it can also fail because the optimizer is entitled to assume that `vp >= &values[0]` is never executed with `vp` not pointing to an element of the array or one beyond it (because doing so would be undefined behavior). Therefore, the optimizer may behave as if this expression is always true and may eliminate it, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In that case, I think your optimizer needs to be less optimizing.

Answer (score 4):

This code is not safe even if old or exotic processor architectures are ruled out.

The optimizer in a compiler embeds many rules about the language. When it sees `vp >= &values[0]`, where `values` is an array, the optimizer is entitled to assume that `vp` points to an array element or one beyond the array, because otherwise the expression is not defined by the C language.

The rules and mechanisms embedded in the optimizer may therefore decide that `vp >= &values[0]` is always true, so it may produce code as if `for (vp = &values[5-1]; ; vp--)` had been written. This results in a loop without a termination condition and further undefined behavior when `*vp = 0` is evaluated with `vp` pointing outside of the array.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but it's probably a bit unlikely, unless you have certain optimization flags set. If I remember correctly, GCC has an option which does break loops like that, but it's disabled by default, and Clangs optimizer won't even touch stuff like that.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Do you maintain that this code is safe according to the C standard, or just safe if you have specific knowledge about certain compilers? Please cite the documentation supporting this.

Answer (score 0):

```
int values[5];
size_t idx;

for(idx=5; idx-- > 0; ) {
   values[idx] = 0;
   }
```

This may look strange at first sight, but once you get used to it it, it can be a good pattern.

- you avoid the (possible) *underflow* of the pointer value (which is strictly undefined)
- You cannot underflow, an unsigned type (such as size_t) will wrap around, which would certainly cause an illegal access, which is preferrable to a sneaky *one-below* adressing, which will corrupt memory instead of *failing fast*.
- WRT to speed/performance: from the compilers point of view, pointers and indexing are basically the same. The compiler may even generate the same code for both cases.

BTW: if you insist on the usage of pointers, the following would do:

```
int *vp, values[5];

for(vp = &values[5-1]; vp ; vp = (vp > &values[0]) ? vp-1 : NULL; ) {
   *vp = 0;
   }
```